# Find the probability that a line contains a point $(p,q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, geometry

Let's define our line as $\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=mx+b \rbrace$, then we need to find the probability that $q = mp+b$.

I don't know what else to do.

EDIT: For example what's the probability that a line passes through the origin? There are an infinite number of lines that passes through the origin but there are also an infinite number of lines that don't. So which is it?

Comment: What is the probability distribution involved?

Comment: It’s probably zero.

Comment: @user113102 If by that you mean the set of possible outcomes, then it's the sell of all possible pair of real numbers \(\mathbb{R}^2\)

Comment: @amd Please check my edit

Comment: The point is you need to specify how you're choosing the lines (or how you are choosing pairs of real numbers in $\mathbb{R}^2$). This is not a meaningful question without this information.

Comment: @user113102 Any line can be used, and any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Right, but for instance pick the line $y=x$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, and $y=x+1$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ and any other line with probability $0$ is a perfectly good probability distribution on the set of all lines, and in this case the answer for $(0,0)$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.